# Input string too long error if using strptime in R

Tags: r, strptime

My file contains a list of timestamps:

```
Fri Feb 14 19:07:31 +0000 2014
Fri Feb 14 19:07:46 +0000 2014
Fri Feb 14 19:07:50 +0000 2014
Fri Feb 14 19:08:04 +0000 2014
```

and reading it into R using:

```
dataset <- read.csv(file="Data.csv")
```

and i then write R commands to enable R to detect the timestamps:

```
time <- strptime(dataset,format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y", tz = "GMT")
```

but I'm constantly getting an error saying:

```
Error in strptime(dataset, format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y") : 
input string is too long
```

it was working well at first but after i added:

```
defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8
```

in my terminal to fix some preferences in R for mac os x, the timestamp command stopped working an keep producing the error i mentioned above.

Comment: Eerily similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963482/strptime-error-in-r-input-string-is-too-long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your original Data. myDates as Character.

```
dtData<-data.frame(myDates=c( "Fri Feb 14 19:07:31 +0000 2014",
                  "Fri Feb 14 19:07:46 +0000 2014",
                  "Fri Feb 14 19:07:50 +0000 2014",
                  "Fri Feb 14 19:08:04 +0000 2014"))
> dtData
                         myDates
1 Fri Feb 14 19:07:31 +0000 2014
2 Fri Feb 14 19:07:46 +0000 2014
3 Fri Feb 14 19:07:50 +0000 2014
4 Fri Feb 14 19:08:04 +0000 2014
```

you need to select dtData$myDates column

```
time <- strptime(dtData$myDates,format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z  %Y", tz = "GMT");time

[1] "2014-02-14 19:07:31 GMT" "2014-02-14 19:07:46 GMT"
[3] "2014-02-14 19:07:50 GMT" "2014-02-14 19:08:04 GMT"
```